# Official Google Cloud Java SDK with examples

Tags: google-compute-engine

Also, is there a sample maven project illustrating Java SDK usage to create Virtual Machine /Instance ?
and also an example illustrating with all dependencies needed and sample code

Looking for very similar to AWS Java SDK to create a VM like at below link
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/ec2/src/main/java/com/example/ec2/CreateInstance.java

Found this one but not sure if this is officially supported SDK.
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java
If there are sample to cerate VM please share.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for Compute Engine Instance creation can be found [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/compute/snippets/CreateInstance.java):

```
/*
 * Copyright 2016 Google LLC
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.cloud.examples.compute.snippets;

import com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions;
import com.google.cloud.compute.v1.AttachedDisk;
import com.google.cloud.compute.v1.AttachedDiskInitializeParams;
import com.google.cloud.compute.v1.Instance;
import com.google.cloud.compute.v1.InstanceClient;
import com.google.cloud.compute.v1.NetworkInterface;
import com.google.cloud.compute.v1.Operation;
import com.google.cloud.compute.v1.ProjectZoneMachineTypeName;
import com.google.cloud.compute.v1.ProjectZoneName;
import java.io.IOException;

/** A snippet for Google Cloud Compute Engine showing how to create a virtual machine instance. */
public class CreateInstance {
  private static final String ZONE = "us-central1-a";
  private static final String DEFAULT_IMAGE =
      "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-7-wheezy-v20150710";
  private static final String DEFAULT_PROJECT = ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId();

  public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    try (InstanceClient instanceClient = InstanceClient.create()) {
      ProjectZoneName zone = ProjectZoneName.of(DEFAULT_PROJECT, ZONE);
      String machineType =
          ProjectZoneMachineTypeName.of("n1-standard-1", DEFAULT_PROJECT, ZONE).toString();
      AttachedDisk disk =
          AttachedDisk.newBuilder()
              .setBoot(true)
              .setAutoDelete(true)
              .setType("PERSISTENT")
              .setInitializeParams(
                  AttachedDiskInitializeParams.newBuilder().setSourceImage(DEFAULT_IMAGE).build())
              .build();
      NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.newBuilder().setName("default").build();
      Instance instanceResource =
          Instance.newBuilder()
              .setName("instance-name")
              .setMachineType(machineType)
              .addDisks(disk)
              .addNetworkInterfaces(networkInterface)
              .build();
      Operation response = instanceClient.insertInstance(zone.toString(), instanceResource);
      if (response.getError() == null) {
        System.out.println("Instance was created successfully");
      } else {
        // inspect operation.getErrors()
        throw new RuntimeException("Instance creation failed");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to use Maven, there is a great tutorial [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/cmdline/README.md) and a Quickstart guide [here](https://github.com/googleapis/java-compute#google-compute-engine-client-for-java).